# cannot fetch values from firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database, progress-bar

**Main activity.java**

```
public class activity_3 extends AppCompatActivity {

   TextView question,option_1,option_2,option_3,description,winnner;
  NumberProgressBar option_progress1, option_progress2,option_progress3;
 int val_1;
 int val_2;
 int val_3;
     DatabaseReference Polldata_3;
    String optionOne;
   String optionTwo;
   String optionThree;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_3);


    final String que =  getIntent().getExtras().getString("que");
    final String des =  getIntent().getExtras().getString("des");
     optionOne =  getIntent().getExtras().getString("option1");
     optionTwo =  getIntent().getExtras().getString("option2");
     optionThree =  getIntent().getExtras().getString("option3");
    final String id_user   =  getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");
    val_1 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("val1");
    val_2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("val2");
    val_2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("val3");
    option_progress1 = (NumberProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.option1_progressbar);
    option_progress2 = (NumberProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.option2_progressbar);
    option_progress3 = (NumberProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.option3_progressbar);

    Polldata_3 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("POll").child("poll_3");

    final DatabaseReference answsersave = Polldata_3.child(id_user);

    question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_showpoll);
    option_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.option_1);
    option_2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.option_2);
    option_3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.option_3);

    description  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description_user_3);
    winnner   = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winner);


    option_1.setText(optionOne);
    option_2.setText(optionTwo);
    option_3.setText(optionThree);
    question.setText(que);
    description.setText(des);


    option_progress1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            option_progress1.setProgress(val_1+1);
            option_progress1.setEnabled(false);
            option_progress2.setEnabled(false);
            option_progress3.setEnabled(false);
            val_1++;


            answsersave.child("option_1_value").setValue(val_1);
            //winnerdeclare();

        }
    });
    option_progress2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            option_progress2.setProgress(val_2+1);
            option_progress1.setEnabled(false);
            option_progress2.setEnabled(false);
            option_progress3.setEnabled(false);
            val_2++;
            answsersave.child("option_2_value").setValue(val_2);
          //  winnerdeclare();

        }
    });

    option_progress3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            option_progress3.setProgress(val_3+1);
            option_progress1.setEnabled(false);
            option_progress2.setEnabled(false);
            option_progress3.setEnabled(false);
            val_3++;
          //  winnerdeclare();
            answsersave.child("option_3_value").setValue(val_3);

        }
    });


}

}
```

**ADAPTER CLASS**

```
public class listview_3 extends AppCompatActivity {


ListView listviewpoll3;
private DatabaseReference Poll_data_3;
List<addpoll_3> addpoll_3List;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview_3);

    listviewpoll3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.poll_listview_3);
    Poll_data_3 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("POll").child("poll_3");

    addpoll_3List = new ArrayList<>();


    listviewpoll3.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(listview_3.this, activity_3.class);
            addpoll_3 poll = addpoll_3List.get(position);
            final String optionone = poll.getOption_1();
            final String optiontwo = poll.getOption_2();
            final String optionthree = poll.getOption_3();
            final String id_user = poll.getId();
            final int value_1 = poll.getOption_1_value();
            final int value_2 = poll.getOption_2_value();
            final int value_3 = poll.getOption_3_value();
            final String question = poll.getQuestion();
            final String desp = poll.getDescription();

            intent.putExtra("option1",optionone);
            intent.putExtra("option2",optiontwo);
            intent.putExtra("option3",optionthree);
            intent.putExtra("id",id_user);
            intent.putExtra("val1",value_1);
            intent.putExtra("val2",value_2);
            intent.putExtra("val3",value_3);
            intent.putExtra("que",question);
            intent.putExtra("descp",desp);



            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

        }

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Poll_data_3.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            addpoll_3List.clear();

            for(DataSnapshot pollSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {

                addpoll_3 poll = pollSnapshot.getValue(addpoll_3.class);

                addpoll_3List.add(poll);
            }

            poll_list_3 adapter =  new poll_list_3(listview_3.this,addpoll_3List);

            listviewpoll3.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

**list class**

```
public class poll_list_3 extends ArrayAdapter<addpoll_3> {

private Activity context;
private List<addpoll_3> addpoll_3List;

public poll_list_3(Activity context, List<addpoll_3> addpoll_3List) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_layout, addpoll_3List);
    this.context = context;
    this.addpoll_3List = addpoll_3List;





}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    View viewitem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout,null);
    TextView textViewName = (TextView) viewitem.findViewById(R.id.tv);
    TextView textViewDesp = (TextView) viewitem.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    final addpoll_3 poll1 = addpoll_3List.get(position);


    textViewName.setText(poll1.getQuestion());
    textViewDesp.setText(poll1.getDescription());

    return viewitem;



}
}
```

I am making a polling app where user can create a poll which is then stored in the firebase database and retrieved into listview of the app
when the user clicks on the list view he is directed to the  the activity where there are number of progressbars
i have added a ON-click listener o the progress bar, So when user clicks on the progressbar the val of that option gets incremented in the database. so when a different user vote on the same poll the value from the database is fetched and value of the current user is added displaying the winner,but problem is the  value of the progressbar1 gets the value from the database but the other two keep progress bar values start from 0 every time user clicks on the other two progress bar (ie 2 and 3).
 please help

addpoll_3.java

```
public class addpoll_3 {


String id;
String question;
String description;
String option_1;
String option_2;
String option_3;
int option_1_value;
int option_2_value;
int option_3_value;

public  addpoll_3(){}



public addpoll_3(String id, String question, String description, String option_1, String option_2, String option_3, int option_1_value, int option_2_value, int option_3_value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.question = question;
    this.description = description;
    this.option_1 = option_1;
    this.option_2 = option_2;
    this.option_3 = option_3;
    this.option_1_value = option_1_value;
    this.option_2_value = option_2_value;
    this.option_3_value = option_3_value;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public String getOption_1() {
    return option_1;
}

public String getOption_2() {
    return option_2;
}

public String getOption_3() {
    return option_3;
}

public int getOption_1_value() {
    return option_1_value;
}

public int getOption_2_value() {
    return option_2_value;
}

public int getOption_3_value() {
    return option_3_value;
}
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9470665/raj-k

Comment: can you post your model class code?

Comment: hie thanks for replying

Comment: you mean class from which data is stored in the database

Comment: this class addpoll_3.class

Comment: added add_poll3 @kdblue

Comment: @kdblue please can you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code:
Activity_3.java

```
val_1 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("val1"); 
val_2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("val2");
val_3 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("val3");
```

These were changes to be made

Answer (score 0):

```
  //Read from the database

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() 

                 {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
```